# Misaligned identation in TOC

Tags: latex, indentation, beamer, tableofcontents

When the section number is at least 10, then the subsection numbers get misaligned with the section titles in the TOC in a beamer presentation in LaTeX. Futhermore, the spacing between the (sub)subsection numbers and the (sub)subsection titles gets smaller. I am looking for a generic way to fix this regardless of whether the section number is at least 10, at least 100, or less than 10. In this case I would not have to tweak these things manually. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass[9pt,trans,xcolor={table},envcountsect]{beamer} % Plain

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme[shownavsym,right]{Aalborg}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol} % Nav symbols
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered] % Automatic enumeration of sections
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ShiftSectionNumber}[1]{%
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\numexpr#1+\beamer@tocsectionnumber}
\makeatother
%
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.14em\rlap{\hskip-2em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsection\par} % Automatic enumeration of subsections. WITH indentation of subsection numbers (\leftskip changed from 3.2em to 3.14em)
%
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=6.9em\rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsubsection\par} % Automatic enumeration of subsubsections. WITH indentation of subsubsection numbers (\leftskip changed from 3.14em to 6.9em, \hskip changed from -2em to -3em)
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%
\def \numbershift {0} % Increasing of enumeration of section numbers and theorems
\ShiftSectionNumber{\numbershift} % Increasing the enumeration of section numbers
\addtocounter{section}{\numbershift} % Theorem numbers follow section numbers
%
%
\section{First Section (1-digit section number)} %What happens if a very long section title is used?} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89708/indent-subsections-in-beamers-toc
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}

\ShiftSectionNumber{8}
\section{Second Section (2-digit section number)} % https://imathworks.com/tex/tex-latex-beamer-how-to-get-subsection-indent-with-a-numbered-toc/
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{Second Subsubsection}

\ShiftSectionNumber{89}
\section{Third Section (3-digit section number)}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
\subsubsection{Third Subsubsection}
%
\begin{frame}[<+->]{Misaligned identation in TOC}
    Hello.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could measure the width of the last section and align the numbers according to this width:

```
\documentclass[9pt,trans,xcolor={table},envcountsect]{beamer} % Plain

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme[shownavsym,right]{Aalborg}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol} % Nav symbols


\begin{document}


\makeatletter

\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\settowidth{\secnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.\space}
\newlength{\subsecnumwidth}
\settowidth{\subsecnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.1\space\space}
\newlength{\subsubsecnumwidth}
\settowidth{\subsubsecnumwidth}{\the\beamer@sectionmax.1.1}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    \makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{\inserttocsectionnumber.}%
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\leavevmode\leftskip=\secnumwidth\rlap{\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\hspace*{\subsecnumwidth}\inserttocsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\leavevmode\leftskip=\dimexpr\subsecnumwidth+\secnumwidth\rlap{\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}\hspace*{\subsubsecnumwidth}\inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\makeatother


\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\begin{frame}[<+->]{Misaligned identation in TOC}
    Hello.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I copy-paste your solution into a new file in overleaf, I get 20 error messages. Apparently the section numbers have disappeared, and the subsections have been pushed to the next line below (and with indentation). I can't figure out what went wrong...?

Comment: @PeterJensen Works fine for me on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dhrwrmktpqqc Are you using texlive2023?

Comment: When I click the link and run it in overleaf, then there is no problem. Everything works fine. I am not sure whether I am using textlive2023 actually. In fact, I don't know what it is? I just have an account on overleaf. Would getting texlive2023 fix the problem?

Comment: @PeterJensen Check the left hand sidebar in overleaf, there you can select the texlive version.

Comment: The indentation of the (sub)subsection numbers relative to the above (sub)section titles is ok. But when I use it in another file, the spacing between the section numbers (at least 2-digit section numbers) and section titles shrink. Is there a way to make the spacing between the section numbers and section titles, the spacing between subsection numbers and subsection titles, and the spacing between subsubsection numbers and subsubsection titles for at least 2-digit section numbers exactly the same as the corresponding spacings in the 1-digit case?

Comment: The spacing between the last section and the section title is constant.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have a short file that displays the problem - can I somehow post it here, or is it better to ask a new question?

Comment: @PeterJensen Please ask a new question